# Strange output of char array converted to int - magic of array[x] - '0'

Tags: arrays, casting, char, buffer, c99

So I'm fooling around with char arrays conversion and testing now this simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    char arr[BUFSIZ];
    printf("Input: ");
    fgets(arr, sizeof(arr), stdin);
    int x = arr[0] - '0';
    printf("Output: %d\n", x);
}
```

The output should be value of variable **x** which is first digit of input.
But, in case of passing negative integer as input I get this:

```
jharvard@appliance (~/CS50/pset1): ./test
Input: -123
Output: -3
```

The output should be **-1**, but is **-3**. Is this *minus* has something to do with array index?
I assume this minus forces compiler to make **array[-1] index** the value of output?

I think that's the point, 'cause after changing the line `int x = arr[0] - '0';` to `int x = arr[1] - '0';`, I get:

```
Input: -123
Output: 1
```

when passing the negative number.

And another example.
When changing that **int x** line to `int x = arr[BUFSIZ - 1] - '0';` I get:

```
jharvard@appliance (~/CS50/pset1): ./test
Input: -123
Output: -40
jharvard@appliance (~/CS50/pset1): ./test
Input: 123
Output: -40
jharvard@appliance (~/CS50/pset1): ./test
Input: 122
Output: -40
jharvard@appliance (~/CS50/pset1): ./test
Input: 890
Output: -40
```

No matter if various positive or negative numbers I pass, the output is always **-40** in this case.

After changing index, e.g. to `int x = arr[BUFSIZ - 2] - '0';` or `int x = arr[BUFSIZ - 7] - '0';` I got different output - sometimes positive or negative, but always this particular number gets printed.

BUFSIZ on my PC is 8192 bytes long.

Comment: I guess the problem is the `-` sign, why not just use `atoi()` instead: `int x = atoi(arr);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you input `-123`, the array is being filled with the characters `'-'`, `'1'`, `'2'`, and `'3'`. The array looks like:

```
arr[0] = '-'
arr[1] = '1'
arr[2] = '2'
arr[3] = '3'
arr[4...BUFSIZ] = ???
```

As you can see, `arr[0]` is the character `'-'`, not the integer `-1`. The numeric value of `'-' (45)` is 3 less than that of `'0' (48)`, hence the output of `-3` when subtracting from `arr[0]`, and the correct output of `1` when you change to `arr[1]`. To see the numerical values of all the standard characters on a keyboard, check out http://www.asciitable.com/

As for outputting from the end of the array, I think that is undefined behavior, because you are not actually assigning anything to those indices.

Comment: Thanks! Here's also good answer to my similar question -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/21699125/170432